# Next JS Audio constructor is not defined

Tags: javascript, next.js, web-audio-api

I understand why this isn't working but I can't find a solution.

My project has a standard Next JS structure.

I have added a `components` directory to the root.

Inside components I have the following component:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Player({url}) {

    const [audio, setAudio] = useState(new Audio(url))

    return (
      <button onClick={ audio.play() }>Play Audio</button>
    )
}
```

This (simplified example) component is being imported into one of my pages.

I am seeing the following error: `ReferenceError: Audio is not defined`

I understand this is because the component is being compiled on the server and NodeJS has no idea what Audio() is.

However I can't find a solution for getting this working.

I have tried importing `useEffect` and setting the state from within it once the component has mounted but this leads to other errors and I gather is not the correct solution.

Any help on best practices for interacting with browser APIs from within NextJS components would be much appreciated.

**Update: Commenter asked for useEffect implementation

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Player({url}) {

  useEffect(() => {
    const [audio, setAudio] = useState(new Audio(url))
  }, [])

  return (
    <button onClick={ audio.play() }>Play Audio</button>
  )
}
```

Returns `ReferenceError: audio is not defined`

Comment: Also share your `useEffect` implementation and what errors are you getting ?

Comment: Updated with useEffect implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useEffect` implementation is wrong. Also, you need to pass a function to `onClick`. Do something like this instead:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Player({ url }) {

  const [audio, setAudio] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => { setAudio(new Audio(url)) }, [])

  return <button onClick={() => { audio?.play() }}>Play Audio</button>
}
```

Also refer: [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-pare-ok8te)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, but this implementation gives me `Error: Invalid hook call.`

Comment: Never mind, I think I might not have saved properly. Thanks @brc-dd, much appreciate the help.